# ::PostMessage to an invalid hWnd

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a thread that calls `::PostMessage(hWnd, [...]);` to send a message to the main thread alerting it to the results of an async operation.

However, I'm concerned that if the thread takes a particularly long time to finish its operation, the `hWnd` may not exist when the `PostMessage` is called (the user may have closed the window).

The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't say anything about the results if `hWnd` is invalid.

**Do you know from experience, or other documentation, about what I can expect if `hWnd` is invalid?**

Comment: Perhaps you should hide the window and not destroy it until the thread is done using it.

Comment: @Ben Voigt:  I agree, but I'm working in a large corp-setting, and don't have control over that kind of architecture choice.

Comment: In a large-corp setting, you can file a bug.  See my answer... The famous Raymond Chen said it's a bug.  Another alternative is to use a `weak_ptr` and invalidate it when the window gets destroyed... although that leaves you with a race condition, the interval between retrieving the HWND from the weak pointer and actually calling `PostMessage`.  So really, you need to keep the window alive.

Comment: Another possible solution is to use any other form of cross-thread queue.

Comment: What I usually do is to hide the window and signal the thread to terminate, (in whatever way works:). When the thread is about to terminate, it PostMessages a last custom message to the window that instructs the window to destroy itself.

Comment: @Harry: Useful, until someone opens a modal dialog. The modal message loop will drop messages posted to a thread, since it isn't associated with a window, and cannot be dispatched using `DispatchMessage`.

Comment: @IInspectable: good point.  I guess you could you work around that with a hook, but it would probably be more sensible to use an entirely different solution (event, thread-safe queue, whatever).

Comment: @Harry: The workaround will not address the initial issue: A thread ID can be reused in much the same way a `HWND` will. As you point out, solving this problem calls for a sane solution.

Comment: @IInspectable: well, no; under the specific conditions described by the OP, that isn't an issue.  The OP controls the lifetime of the thread but not the lifetime of the window.  But I concede that PostThreadMessage wasn't a sensible suggestion, so I'll delete the original comment.

Answer (score 3):

Raymond Chen wrote about this:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/16/3885472.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/17/3903614.aspx

Some choice excerpts:

> It so happens that boatloads of programs (and "boatloads" is a technical term) contain bugs where they use window handles after the window has been destroyed. When a window handle is re-used, that program sends a message to the window it thinks is still there, but instead it sends the message to a completely unrelated window. This doesn't bode well for the program, and it usually doesn't bode well for the new window that received the message by mistake either.

---

> We left off our story last time by raising the problem of programs that send messages to windows that have already been destroyed and how window handle re-use exacerbates the problem. Although **this is clearly a bug in the programs that use window handles after destroying the window**, the problem is so widespread that the window manager folks in Windows NT decided to take a more proactive approach.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, Ramond Chen explained what happens if the `HWND` gets re-used by a new window.  `PostMessage()` will succeed, it will just go to the wrong window.  However, in cases where the `HWND` does not get re-used, `PostMessage()` will fail with an `ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE` (1400) error code.

Comment: Nice answer Remy. I have similar concerns: how to make sure the window is alive before posting a message to it from a different thread? ie the user has not closed the window? i got the same question as the OP but i got now clear answer yet.

Comment: @amaninlove checking if the window is valid before posting to it is a race condition. Simply don't destroy the window until after the thread is done posting to it. Or create a dedicated [message-only window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows) for the thread to post to.

Comment: The problem is how to make sure that thread is still posting. I think that needs some kind of lock mechanism. What about posting to the parent window and then the parent itself checks to see if the child window is still valid?

Comment: It is your responsibility to keep track of whether your threads are running or not.  Simply don't destroy the window while the thread is still running. When the thread ends, then you can destroy the window.  Otherwise, when you are about to destroy the window, terminate the thread first and wait for it to fully terminate before actually destroying the window

Comment: Good solution but my threads don't terminate,  they stay with the application lifetime

Comment: Then I suggest the threads post only to an HWND that you have full control over its lifetime, so you can ensure it does not get destroyed prematurely.  A [message-only window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows) would be such an HWND

Comment: Message-only window sounds good. Will posting to parent window be okay? provided that it stays with the application's lifetime. The parent window can check if child window exists since its the main thread and its synchronized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181512/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-a-man-in-love).